# Get a string list from a word

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, cpu-word

I'm trying to invert items of a dictionary containing strings as key and string list as value:

```
dico = {'key1': [],
        'key2': [],
        'key3': ['value1', 'value1'],
        'key4': ['value2', 'value2'],
        'key5': ['value3'],
        'key6': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}

new_dict = {}

for key, values in dico.items():
    if values:
        for value in values:
            try:
                if key not in new_dict[value]:
                    new_dict[value].append(key)
            except KeyError:
                new_dict[values[0]] = list(key)
            else:
                print('ERROR')
```

Here's the result expected:

```
#Expected
new_dict = {'value1': ['key3', 'key6'],
            'value2': ['key4', 'key6'],
            'value3': ['key5', 'key6']}
#Reality
new_dict = {'value1': ["k", "e", "y", "3", "k", "e", "y", "6"],
            'value2': ["k", "e", "y", "4", "k", "e", "y", "6"],
            'value3': ["k", "e", "y", "5", "k", "e", "y", "6"]}
```

I noticed if I change that:

```
new_dict[values[0]] = list(key)
```

by that:

```
new_dict[values[0]] = []
new_dict[values[0]].append(key)
```

It actually works but is there another way to do it in one line ?

Comment: How about `new_dict[values[0]] = [key]`?

Comment: What is `pretty_dict` here?

Comment: Note that `list('key1')` evaluates to `['k', 'e', 'y', '1']` the second actually evaluates to `['key1']`

Comment: Not related to the problem but unless there's more code that's omitted here, you don't need the `if values:` check. The for-loop won't run if there are no values.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying so fast and so accurately. It helped me! :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh! I'm sorry! I didn't do it on purpose. ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are turning your keys to lists:

```
new_dict[values[0]] = list(key)
```

That'll produce a list with individual characters. Use a list literal instead:

```
new_dict[values[0]] = [key]
```

You can use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to handle missing keys in `new_dict` to simplify your code. It looks like you want to produce *sets* instead; sets track *unique* values and saves you having to do explicit tests for duplicates.

```
for key, values in dico.items():
    for value in values:
        new_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
```

You can always turn those sets back to lists afterwards:

```
new_dict = {key: list(values) for key, values in new_dict.items()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> dico = {'key1': [],
...         'key2': [],
...         'key3': ['value1', 'value1'],
...         'key4': ['value2', 'value2'],
...         'key5': ['value3'],
...         'key6': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
>>> new_dict = {}
>>> for key, values in dico.items():
...     for value in values:
...         new_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
... 
>>> new_dict
{'value3': set(['key6', 'key5']), 'value2': set(['key6', 'key4']), 'value1': set(['key3', 'key6'])}
>>> {key: list(values) for key, values in new_dict.items()}
{'value3': ['key6', 'key5'], 'value2': ['key6', 'key4'], 'value1': ['key3', 'key6']}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Iterate every item from main `dico` dictionary.
2. Check if value is present or not.
3. Iterate every item from value.
4. Use `set` method to remove duplicate values.
5. Add to `new_dict` dictionary where value is key and key is list value.

code:

```
dico = {'key1': [],
        'key2': [],
        'key3': ['value1', 'value1'],
        'key4': ['value2', 'value2'],
        'key5': ['value3'],
        'key6': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}

new_dict = {}

for key, values in dico.items():
    if values:
        for value in set(values):
            try:
                new_dict[value].append(key)
            except:
                new_dict[value] = [key]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
{'value1': ['key3', 'key6'],
 'value2': ['key6', 'key4'],
 'value3': ['key6', 'key5']}
```

Comment: This now produces a list with duplicate keys however. The OP seems to be keen to produce sequences of unique keys per value. `key3` appears *twice* for `value1` in your output.

Comment: yes, updated, now used `set` to remove duplicate values from list.

Comment: Nice, indeed it is the values *per key* that must be unique.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, thank you. :) you are too fast and too accurate to every answer. How I can reach to you? I want to learn more and more python

Comment: My profile has information on how I can be contacted for expert support.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you, I have send request on linkedin.